# New deployment of Azure VMSS with system assigned Managed identity fails

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-managed-identity

I'm encountering an issue wherein new deployment for azure vmss (which has managed identity enabled) fails for the first time due to the following error -

***Code: ResourceNotFound. 
Message: The Resource 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/' under resource group '' was not found***

Following are the relevant snippets of my arm template -

VMSS section-

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets",
  "sku": {
    "name": "[parameters('vmNodeType0Size')]",
    "capacity": "[parameters('defaultVMScaleSetSize')]",
    "tier": "Standard"
  },
  "name": "[variables('vmNodeType0Name')]",
  "apiVersion": "[variables('vmssApiVersion')]",
  "location": "[parameters('computeLocation')]",
  "tags": {
    "resourceType": "Service Fabric",
    "clusterName": "[variables('cloudClusterName')]"
  },
  "identity": {
    "type": "systemAssigned"
  },
  "properties": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Access policy section -

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies",
  "name": "[concat(variables('KeyVaultName'), '/add')]",
  "apiVersion": "2018-02-14",
  "properties": {
    "accessPolicies": [
      {
        "tenantId": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/',  variables('vmNodeType0Name'), '/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/Identities/default'), '2015-08-31-PREVIEW').tenantId]",
        "objectId": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/',  variables('vmNodeType0Name'), '/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/Identities/default'), '2015-08-31-PREVIEW').principalId]",
        "permissions": {
          "keys": [
            "get"
          ],
          "secrets": [
            "get",
            "set"
          ],
          "certificates": [
            "get"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/',  variables('KeyVaultName'))]"
  ]
}
```

It seems that ARM tries to deploy managed identity for VMSS even before VMSS itself is created and hence it fails. I have found no way to add a dependency on VMSS creation for managed identity creation. Subsequent deployments succeed as VMSS is already created by that point.

Answer (score 1):

try adding the following to the KV resource:

```
"dependsOn": [ "[variables('vmNodeType0Name')]" ]
```

if that doesnt work, wrap adding the access policies to the KV into a linked template deployment and make that deployment depend on the vmss provision. that would always work.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible for me as my VM Scale set is dependent on KeyVault (to install certificates as part of vaultCertificates node). Moreover, why should adding a dependency on KeyVault, fix provisioning order for the Managed identity of scale set?

Comment: because this is not the scale set error, this is the KV error, it fails to wait for the scale set to complete installing and tries to retrieve managed identities. also, its possible to move anything to a linked template anyway

Comment: I tried this approach too and it didn't work either. At this point, I believe this is a bug with how arm deploys managed identities for scale sets.

Comment: just use a linked template and it will work just fine